# Assigning href link from custom post type from wordpress beside each song in jPlayer playlist

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, jplayer

I'm trying to add a buy button beside each song that links to itunes. Unfortunately, I'm new to jPlayer and have absolutely no idea where to start. The jPlayer already exists in the wordpress theme I bought, everything has been setup nicely and am really only needing this last additional feature.

Everything should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwCGr.png

As of now, I've inspected the javascript file and have successfully added a link beside each of the song in the playlist. However, the links are static and I need them to be linked to a field from custom post type in wordpress. The codes are below:

```js
//The added buy on itunes link is below with a class .playlist-item-buy
_createListItem: function(b) {
      var c = this,
        d = "<li><div>";
      if (d += "<a href='javascript:;' class='" + this.options.playlistOptions.removeItemClass + "'>&times;</a>", b.free) {
        var e = !0;
        d += "<span class='" + this.options.playlistOptions.freeGroupClass + "'>(", a.each(b, function(b, f) {
          a.jPlayer.prototype.format[b] && (e ? e = !1 : d += " | ", d += "<a class='" + c.options.playlistOptions.freeItemClass + "' href='" + f + "' tabindex='-1'>" + b + "</a>")
        }), d += ")</span>"
      }
      return d += "<a href='javascript:;' class='" + this.options.playlistOptions.itemClass + "' tabindex='0'>" + b.title + (b.artist ? " <span class='jp-artist'>by " + b.artist + "</span>" : "") + "</a>", d + "<a href='#' class='playlist-item-buy'>Buy on iTunes</a>" + "</div></li>"
    },
```

```js
//This is the metabox. I've succesfully added a "link to itunes field" to the bottom of the code.
$meta_boxes[] = array(
  'id'         => 'album_demo',
  'title'      => __( 'Album Demo', 'cmb' ),
  'pages'      => array( 'album', ),
  'fields'     => array(
   array(
    'id'          => $prefix . 'album_demo',
    'type'        => 'group',
    'description' => __( 'Upload mp3 and ogg files', 'cmb' ),
    'options'     => array(
     'group_title'   => __( 'Single {#}', 'cmb' ), // {#} gets replaced by row number
     'add_button'    => __( 'Add Another Single', 'cmb' ),
     'remove_button' => __( 'Remove Single', 'cmb' ),
     'sortable'      => true, // beta
    ),
    // Fields array works the same, except id's only need to be unique for this group. Prefix is not needed.
    'fields'      => array(
     array(
      'name' => 'Entry Title',
      'id'   => 'single_title',
      'type' => 'text',
      // 'repeatable' => true, // Repeatable fields are supported w/in repeatable groups (for most types)
     ),
     array(
      'name' => 'Mp3 link',
      'id'   => 'single_mp3',
      'type' => 'text',
      // 'repeatable' => true, // Repeatable fields are supported w/in repeatable groups (for most types)
     ),
     array(
      'name' => 'Ogg Link',
      'id'   => 'single_ogg',
      'type' => 'text',
      // 'repeatable' => true, // Repeatable fields are supported w/in repeatable groups (for most types)
     ),
     array(
      'name' => 'iTunes Link',
      'id'   => 'single_itunes',
      'type' => 'text',
      // 'repeatable' => true, // Repeatable fields are supported w/in repeatable groups (for most types)
     ),
    ),
   ),
  ),
 );
```

The trouble I'm having right now is having to link these 2 together. I can provide further code snippets that aren't posted here if it would help.

Comment: You want to manually add the iTunes purchase link via the Wordpress Back-office?  It may be easier to just program a script that will search the 'artist' + 'title' via iTunes API and append the buy button div to each listItem.

Comment: I get that I need to add the button div to each list item, but the number of songs in the list varies depending on how many there are in the album. What I need to find is where this is generated so I can insert the div for the button.